# Creating a list of top 5 occuring UNIQUE values (text) between 2 date ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am hoping someone can help me. I am aiming to create a list of unique values (in this case email addresses) that occur the most in a column between 2 date ranges. I have 1 sheet with data (sheet 1) and another where I am creating this list (sheet 2).

So far I have managed to do this by adding a new column in sheet 1 with =IF(D2="","",COUNTIF(D:D,D2)) to the data.

Then using the below to list all unique values + count (sheet2)
=SORT(UNIQUE({'1st line appeals data'!B:B,'1st line appeals data'!D:D}))

Then using  the below to select the top 5 occuring text + count (sheet 2)
=QUERY(AF:AG,"Select AF, AG where AF<>'' Order by AG Desc limit 5")

This works perfectly but what I want to do now is to add a between and to date value to the top 5.
In sheet 2, A5 I have date from value and sheet 2,A6 I have date to.

The numbers represented in A5,A6 are week numbers. I am hoping to reference them to the week numbers listed in sheet 2 something like - '1st line appeals data'!$A:$A,">="&$A$5,'1st line appeals data'!$A:$A,"<="&$A$6

Demo sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMJ17LM7iA9a18WGbJ2IIuQAU_aS49cyn2K2X1bp6ts/edit#gid=0

Any help would be hugely appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That will make it a lot easier to find a working solution for you.

Comment: We can't access the spreadsheet you shared. Please fix permissions so that 'anyone with the link can edit'.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry about that, I have duplicated the sheet here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMJ17LM7iA9a18WGbJ2IIuQAU_aS49cyn2K2X1bp6ts/edit#gid=0

B19 = top 5 email addresses
AE15:AF = Unique values

Hoping for the list shown in B19 to primarily be filtered by week num (A5+A6) and also if possible by site (shown in column F in the data sheet)
Thanks

Comment: There is one thing that I don't understand - do you want to retrieve those records with the dates between these two week numbers?

Comment: Yes thats correct - Not to worry this has now been resolved. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer here for documentation purposes? @shyshy999